# search data from FileReader in Java

Tags: java, swing

---

how to read and search data from file (txt) and then display the data in TextArea or Jtable.
for example I have file txt contains data and I need to display this data in textarea after I clicked a button, I have used FileReader , and t1 t2 tp are attributes  in the file

```
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;

 String t1,t2,tp;    
Ffile f1= new Ffile();
FileReader fin = new FileReader("test2.txt");

Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);

while (src.hasNext()) {
     t1 = src.next();
     textarea.setText(t1);
     t2 = src.next();
     textarea.setText(t2);
     tp = src.next();
     textarea.setText(tp);

     f1.insert(t1,t2,tp);
}

fin.close();
```

also I have used the inputstream

```
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    String dbRecord = null;

    try { 

       File f = new File("text2.text");
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f); 
       BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis); 
       dis = new DataInputStream
       while ( (dbRecord = dis.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(dbRecord, ":");
          String t1 = st.nextToken();
          String t2 = st.nextToken();
          String tp  = st.nextToken();
          textarea.setText(textarea.getText()+t1);
          textarea.setText(textarea.getText()+t2);
          textarea.setText(textarea.getText()+tp);

      }


    } catch (IOException e) { 
       // catch io errors from FileInputStream or readLine() 
       System.out.println("Uh oh, got an IOException error: " + e.getMessage()); 

    } finally { 
    }
```

but both of them don't work ,so please any one help me 
I want to know how to read data and also search it from file and i need to display the data in textarea .

thanks in advance

---

update the question

---

Firstly, thank you so much for those who answered my question.

secondly, To explain more , I want to read data from a file and  display it in a TextArea
so anyone have code to do this please show it to me becuase I have tried a lot and I still have same problem.

Comment: It's unclear how it "don't work". What happens? What happens not? If you got an exception, please replace `System.out.println()` by `e.printStackTrace()` or just a `throw`. It's unclear as well what format exactly the textfile is in. Can you please update your question with an excerpt of the textfile in the exact format? (in code blocks).

Comment: Please post short, self-contained, compilable examples. See http://sscce.org/ for details.

Answer (score 3):

```
textArea.setText(...);
```

replaces the existing text in the text area. I think you are looking for

```
textArea.append(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

//Import necessary packages
public class FileRead implements ActionListener {
    JFrame jf=new JFrame("Sample");
    JTextArea jt=new JTextArea();
    JButton jb=new JButton("Click Me");
    public FileRead()
    {
     jf.setSize(300,200);
     jt.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     jf.add(jb,BorderLayout.NORTH);
     jf.add(jt,BorderLayout.CENTER);
     jb.addActionListener(this);
     jf.setVisible(true);
     jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
    public static void main(String as[])
    {
        new FileRead();
    }

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==jb)
    {
    File f=new File("D:\\a.txt");
try
{
Scanner s=new Scanner(f);
while(s.hasNext())
{
    jt.append(s.nextLine());
    jt.append("\n");
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println(""+ex);
}
}
}
```

}